# DBT - Use dynamic array for Pivot

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, jinja2, dbt

I would like to use DBT to pivot a column in my BigQuery table.

Since I have more than 100 values, I want my pivoted column to be dynamic, I would like something like that:

```
select *
    from (  select ceiu.value, ceiu.user_id, ce.name as name
            from company_entity_item_user ceiu
            left join company_entity ce on ce.id = ceiu.company_entity_id)
    PIVOT(STRING_AGG(value) FOR name IN (select distinct name from company_entity))
```

The problem here is I can't use a `SELECT` statement inside `IN`.
I know I can use Jinja templates with DBT, it could look like this:

```
...
    PIVOT(STRING_AGG(value) FOR name IN ('{{unique_company_entities}}'))
...
```

But I have no idea how to use a `SELECT` statement to create such variable.
Also, since I am using BigQuery, I tried using `DECLARE` and `SET` but I don't know how to use them in DBT, if it is even possible.

Thank for your help

Comment: Not sure in what format you need to present the actual values after the `FOR name IN (...)`, but instead of a select statement, you could use dbt_utils's macro `get_column_values` to achieve the exact same thing: https://github.com/dbt-labs/dbt-utils#get_column_values-source

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Elevating the comment by @aleix-cc to an answer, because that is the best way to do this in dbt.

To get data from your database into the jinja context, you can use dbt's built-in [`run_query`](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/dbt-jinja-functions/run_query) macro. Or if you don't mind using the `dbt-utils` package, you can use the [`get_column_values`](https://github.com/dbt-labs/dbt-utils#get_column_values-source) macro from that package, which will return a list of the distinct values in that column (it also guards the call to `run_query` with an `{% if execute %}` statement, which is critical to preventing dbt compilation errors).

Assuming `company_entity` is already a dbt model, your model becomes:

```sql
{% set company_list = dbt_utils.get_column_values(table=ref('company_entity'), column='name') %}
# company_list is a jinja list of strings. We need a comma-separated
# list of single-quoted string literals
{% set company_csv = "'" ~ company_list | join("', '") ~ "'" %}

select *
    from (  select ceiu.value, ceiu.user_id, ce.name as name
            from company_entity_item_user ceiu
            left join company_entity ce on ce.id = ceiu.company_entity_id)
    PIVOT(STRING_AGG(value) FOR name IN ({{ company_csv }})
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, that's what I ended up doing. I put the macro into a specific file for clarity.